# Use context to configure apollo link in root of react app

Tags: reactjs

I have the below provider / hook,

```
interface IAccessTokenContext {
  accessToken: string
  setAccessToken: (token: string) => void
}

const accessTokenContext = createContext<IAccessTokenContext | null>(null)

export const AccessTokenProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")

  const memoizedContextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      accessToken,
      setAccessToken,
    }),
    [accessToken, setAccessToken]
  )

  return (
    <accessTokenContext.Provider value={memoizedContextValue}>
      {children}
    </accessTokenContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAccessToken = () => {
  const context = useContext(accessTokenContext)

  if (!context) {
    throw Error("Need context")
  }

  return context
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to use the context in the root of my app, I assume this is not possible, what could be an alternative approach since I want to access the token and set it in the root but also inside components

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const { accessToken, setAccessToken } = useAccessToken()

const requestLink = new ApolloLink(
  (operation, forward) =>
    new Observable(observer => {
      let handle: ZenObservable.Subscription

      Promise.resolve(operation)
        .then(operation => {
          if (accessToken) {
...
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the token in browser's local storage and then you can read it from local storage anywhere in your App.
Something like

```
localStorage.setItem('token', value);
```

Then read it like

```
localStorage.getItem('token')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Storing tokens in local storage, beats the whole purpose of having tokens over cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Contexts can not only store the values but also objects or functions.

Use state at the top level component.

`const [token, setToken] = useState() ;`
`<TokenSetterContext.Provider value={setToken} >`
And manage this state to your existing context or similar approach.

Comment: Isn't that what I have already tho? the problem is that I need to access that value in my top level code

Comment: May be I didn't explain well. From top level, pass on a state method that's part of context that updates context value.

Comment: Could you provide me with a minimal example? I would really appreciate it